# Illustrator Inner Glow Looks Pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pixelation

Is there anyway to make it softer? Everything else in the shot is crisp, but you can see the pixels of the inner glow pretty easily. [image: pixels]

[image]

Comment: What are your Document Raster Effects Settings? (In the Effect Menu)

Comment: what is the zoom level of this image, and possibly more important... the final size of the image. If you are zoomed in 500% and the final image is less that 100x100 i doubt it will even be noticed.

Comment: @scott, That was the problem. I was at 72ppi not 300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You often need to set the **Document Raster Effects Settings (DRES)** in the `Effects` Menu to work correctly if you are using effects which are raster based, such as glows and shadows.

[image]

[image]

Even if you are creating artwork for screen output it can help to increase the DRES setting. However, be aware, a higher DRES means *slower* screen redrawing for raster effects.